# Is it possible to perform kNN imputation for missing values in time-series data?

Tags: time-series, missing-data, k-nearest-neighbour

I have energy consumption data containing the time values and and corresponding consumption values in kWh. I want to perform imputation in R.

Comment: What are the features that you'll use for determining the nearest neighbors?

Comment: I have half-hourly energy consumption information. Same I will use for filling the missing values. With data values, I have 48 columns containing consumption at the prticular time.